# GDAL does not ignore NoData value

Tags: raster, gdal, statistics

I am trying to calcualate the statistics of a TIFF. The script should ignore the NoData value, but doesn't. What causes this?

```py
import gdal
from gdalconst import *

# register all of the drivers
gdal.AllRegister()

# open the image
ds = gdal.Open('test_slope.tif', GA_ReadOnly)

# get raster band 1
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# set NoData value
band.SetNoDataValue(-3.4028230607371e+38)

# Calculate and print Statistics
stats = band.GetStatistics(0,1)
print stats
```

The results look like this

```
>>> 
[-3.4028230607371e+38, 126.5991897583, -4.6432918375055e+37, 1.1680875238428e+38]
>>>
```

Comment: don't cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351104/gdal-does-not-ignore-nodata-value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GetStatistics will reuse previously computed statistics if they exist (i.e computed before you set the NoData value).  You can use `stats = band.ComputeStatistics(0)` instead of GetStatistics to force the statistics to be recomputed.

Comment: ComputeStatistics worked. It ignored the nodata value. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The API documentation doesn't specify how NoData is used when calculating statistics. All clues in your results demonstrate that NoData was not ignored in the statistical calculations, which is a pity.

I normally use a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) to make calculations on arrays with missing values:

```
import numpy as np

# Read into NumPy array
array = band.ReadAsArray()

nodata = band.GetNoDataValue()
if nodata is not None:
    array = np.ma.masked_equal(array, nodata)

print('min: %s, max: %s, mean: %s, std: %s' %
      (array.min(), array.max(), array.mean(), array.std()))
```

Lastly, if you had opened the raster with `GA_Update` mode, you can write these to the data source:

```
band.SetStatistics(np.asscalar(array.min()), np.asscalar(array.max()),
                   np.asscalar(array.mean()), np.asscalar(array.std()))
```

Comment: The masked array also does not ignore the NoData Value.