# Statistical properties of raster image

Tags: qgis, python, raster, zonal-statistics, numpy

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a raster image. In QGIS zonal statistics, we can calculate it within a polygon or a vector. But I want to calculate for the whole image. In Python, I'm getting the same value for an image that I'm giving as input. How can I resolve this one...?

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
g = gdal.Open('ndvi.tif')
ndvi = g.ReadAsArray()
ndvi = np.array(ndvi, dtype = float)
M_ndvi = ndvi.mean()
Std_ndvi = ndvi.std()
```

I tried this for different images, but the mean and standard deviation output is same for all.

Comment: If you get the same statistics for all images, have you considered that you may do it wrong with your code?

Comment: Confirmed that the band.ComputeStatistics(0) method from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54150/gdal-does-not-ignore-nodata-value works. You must have a problem with your Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS, Go to `Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Information`. In the drop down list select the image you want and click OK. Among the information you will receive from the image, you will also get the minimum, maximum, mean and standard deviation of the image as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

These lines of code are working:

```
import optparse, warnings,sys,os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import *
from osgeo import gdal,ogr,osr
gdal.UseExceptions()
import osgeo
osgeo.ogr.UseExceptions()
import gdal
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

g_red = gdal.Open(r'band4.tif')
g_nir = gdal.Open(r'band5.tif')
red = g_red.ReadAsArray()
nir = g_nir.ReadAsArray()
red = np.array(red, dtype = float)
nir = np.array(nir, dtype = float)
check = np.logical_and ( red > 1, nir > 1 )
ndvi = np.where ( check,  (nir - red ) / ( nir + red ), -999 )

noDataVal = ndvi.GetNoDataValue(); print('no data value:',noDataVal)
scaleFactor = ndvi.GetScale(); print('scale factor:',scaleFactor)
ndvi_stats = ndvi.GetStatistics(True,True)

print('NDVI Statistics: Minimum=%.2f, Maximum=%.2f, Mean=%.3f, StDev=%.3f' %(ndvi_stats[0], ndvi_stats[1], ndvi_stats[2], ndvi_stats[3]))
```